# Spring and Jersey rest api returned 404

Tags: spring, tomcat, servlets, jersey

i tried to make rest api with spring and jersey.
this is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/FjordRestApi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and this is my service file:

```
package com.persistent.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.persistent.entity.User;
import com.persistent.entity.UsersList;

@Path("/us")
@Component
public class UsersService {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @GET
    @Transactional
    @Path("/getUsers")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public UsersList getUsers() {
        final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("risk", 1));
        return new UsersList(criteria.list());
    }
}
```

when i used ServletRunner with the method getResponse 
like this:

```
public void testFoo() {
    WebResponse response;
    try {
        response = getClient().getResponse("http://localhost:8282/FjordRestApi/us/getUsers");
        System.out.println(response.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">  

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.persistent</groupId>
    <artifactId>FjordRestApi</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FjordRestApi</name>

    <build>
        <!-- <finalName>jerseySpringJPA</finalName> -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.5.v20100705</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webApp>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</webApp>
                    <!--<systemPropertiesFile>${build.testOutputDirectory}/change-service.properties</systemPropertiesFile> -->
                    <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <!--<contextPath>/v1</contextPath> -->
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>database.properties</name>
                            <value>file:${project.basedir}/target/test-classes/database.properties</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>jetty.port</name>
                            <value>${jetty.port}</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jersey.version>1.1.4.1</jersey.version>
        <!-- Avoids MacRoman encoding on OSX -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <jetty.port>8282</jetty.port>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Unit Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>httpunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.test</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <!-- These exclusions keep jersey-spring dependencies on spring 2.0 from 
                getting resolved by maven -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.transaction</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- In Memory Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey Support for JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- This is LAST for a reason, dbunit dependencies load older versions 
            of log4j which causes issues with spring bean loader -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- My favorite java library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>r08</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <!-- Jersey Official Maven Repo -->
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Spring Official Maven Repo -->
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
            <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Hibernate Official Maven Repo -->
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

its returned the correct json text but when i went to the url directly i got 404 error, such as when i run postman get request i got 404 error page.

the console not showing anything when i did above steps.

what can i do?
tnx a lot

Comment: If one is working and one is not, you need to post the complete client code and post an image of the postman request. This way we can help you find what is different.

Answer (score 0):

I think your configurations needs to add init-param for jersey ( depends on your version of jersey ofcourse ) .
try to add :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>
          com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
        </param-name>
        <param-value>your package</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I advice you to read the docs of jersey for the [providers config](https://jersey.github.io/#PROVIDER_PACKAGES)
,if doesn't work ( depends on jersey version, try to change 
 com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
by
jersey.config.server.provider.packages

Comment: Tnx for your help, the two changes didnt help...nothing changed actually i used this code: https://github.com/thrawn01/Spring-Jersey-Hibernate-DbUnit-Example and i changed names

Comment: Ofcourse  you have to change the " your package" by  com.persistent.rest your package

Comment: where is the dependency for hsqldb ?  if there is error in console , it can help us to know what's wrong

Comment: I tried the exemple , and your code , you just need to add hsql dependency and all work fine.

Comment: tnx for your help, i changed it to working with mysql so i removed hsqldb and add mysql...